# problem with shadow volume using opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow, stencil-buffer

I cannot figure out a solution to my shadown projections using
shadow volumes and stencil buffers. The problem can be viewed in:
[www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~ricfow/shadowProblem.avi](http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~ricfow/shadowProblem.avi)

In this other video:
[www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~ricfow/shadowProblemAux.avi](http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~ricfow/shadowProblemAux.avi)
only the faces associated to the silhouettes have been draw,
where blue means front face and red back face.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Some relevant code snippets of yours would surely help to find your problem.

Comment: Basically, I followed nehe lesson 27.

Comment: But as long as we don't see your code, we cannot just rely on you following the NeHe lesson. Just post it.

Comment: Problem solved. Some edges beloging to the silhouettes were being extruded twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Some edges beloging to the silhouettes were being extruded twice. Thanks.